# Hoefler Text Swashes under Windows 7 XeTex

Tags: xetex, windows, hoefler

I'm using XeTeX on Windows 7 from the MiKTeX 2.9 package and I want to use the swashes from Hoefler Text. The common ligatures rendering well but I can't get the swashes.
Here's the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Ligatures={Common,Rare,Historic}, Alternate=1]{Hoefler Text}
\fontsize{24pt}{30pt}\selectfont 
\noindent
Que dictes \emph{vous} de mon appel, \\
Toute beste \& garde sa pel \\
ff fl fi ffl ffi
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this ("Q" without swash):

[image: without swashes]

But it should look like this:

[image: with swashes]

More samples: http://www.typography.com/fonts/hoefler-text/features/hoefler-text-grand-italics

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Just for comparison: Your code, when run on a Mac (MacOSX 10.9.4, and either MacTeX2014 or MacTeX2013) produces the desired output, i.e., the second image you've posted. (Actually, it also produces "swashy" ampersand symbol, since that's what's in your code.) Hopefully some MikTeX users can provide advice.

Comment: Do you have the same version of the font, though?

Comment: @Mico Without the actual font it is not possible to test this and imho there is no free version of the font for windows.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Ah, I'd forgotten that whereas Hoefler Text is distributed as a system font with MacOSX, that's not the case with Windows. Maybe the OP will provide some more information as to the provenance of this font that's on his/her Windows system.

Comment: @Mico - The font is copied from MacOSX (font version 8.0 from 2007).

Comment: @Dr.Brown - The fact that the font file is copied from a Mac *could be* (but isn't necessarily) the source of the problem: The version of Hoefler Text that's available on Macs has various AAT ("Apple Advanced Technology"...) features that are of no use on other operating systems. That said, I should mention that I've never copied a Mac/AAT font file to Windows to investigate what might happen in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

That may be due to the reason that Hoefler Text uses special AAT (Apple Advance Typography) features for the swashes. As Windows supports the Opentype ones, XeLaTeX doesn't support them, so, what I do (I love that font and I've been working with it for many years), is that I replace manually in TexWorks the normal capital "Q" character with the *swashed* one, at the end of documment writting. I know it's a bit tedious, but it's the price we have to pay to use that amazing font. 
I just don't see why Hoefler&Frere-Jones don't release an opentype-optimized version of the font, given that it's the standard in design right now ...

PS: For the italic swashes, I set `\fontspec{Hoefler Text Swash}` manually for that particular text, and once I have finished the party that I wanted to appear with italic swashs, I just returned to the original font using `\fontspec{Hoefler Text}`.